# Using st's scrollback patch with dvtm or tmux

Tags: tmux, suckless-terminal

When running suckless' st terminal with the scrollback patch in conjunction with dvtm or tmux, the scrollback (patch) only shows blank lines (empty black space).

This doesn't seem to be a problem when running GNU screen. Is there a way to fix it?

---

scrollback patch: https://st.suckless.org/patches/scrollback/

dvtm: https://github.com/martanne/dvtm

tmux: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope :(. I think may have something to do with TMUX spawning its own process. More on that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591756/suckless-dwm-swallow-patch-tmux).
Not too sure about DVTM though, sorry.

Comment: I haven't looked at the code, but this repo has st working with scrollback in tmux. The commit says something about external piping. And I've officially switched to st https://github.com/lukesmithxyz/st

Comment: [This](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/st/commit/7e6e779130327e065fcf587afa80f13150d0de31) looks like modification to two existing patches, [externalpipe](https://st.suckless.org/patches/externalpipe/) and [scrollback](https://st.suckless.org/patches/scrollback/).

Didn't work for me when I applied a similar modification, but I'll dig deeper into it later.
Thanks heaps for sharing though :)!

Comment: No worries. Let me know if you figure it out exactly.